# Opening two edge tab side by side with powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I've been trying to create a script that will open two edge tab side by side but my script isn't working and there is no error showing up:

This is the script

```
# On lance les deux instances de Edge
$edge1 = Start-Process -FilePath "msedge.exe" -PassThru
$edge2 = Start-Process -FilePath "msedge.exe" -PassThru

# Fonction pour attendre que la fenêtre soit ouverte
start-sleep 8

# On attend que les fenêtres soient ouvertes et chargées
$edge1Window = Wait-ForWindowOpen -Process $edge1
$edge2Window = Wait-ForWindowOpen -Process $edge2

$win1 = [System.Windows.Window]::new()
$win2 = [System.Windows.Window]::new()

# On redimensionne les fenêtres
if ($edge1Window -and $edge1Window.GetType().Name -eq "IntPtr") {
    $source = [System.Windows.PresentationSource]::FromVisual([System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource]::FromHwnd($edge1Window))
    $win1 = $source.RootVisual
    $win1.Width = 300
    $win1.Height = 800
    $win1.WindowState = 'Normal'
}
if ($edge2Window -and $edge2Window.GetType().Name -eq "IntPtr") {
    $source = [System.Windows.PresentationSource]::FromVisual([System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource]::FromHwnd($edge2Window))
    $win2 = $source.RootVisual
    $win2.Width = 800
    $win2.Height = 600
    $win2.WindowState = 'Normal'
    }
```

Right now two edge tab open but they are not moved and place side by side.

My pc is currently running on Win10 21h2

Comment: This is not a Windows OS version issue. This ```Wait-ForWindowOpen``` is not a PowerShell (WinPS/PSCore) cmdlet or function. Where are you getting this from? Did you create it or get in from another's GitHub repo or is it a module cmdlet from something you installed from the MS powershellgallery.com? If that function/cmdlet is what you are using to do this, then, it's not a PS issue, it's that function/cmdlet not functioning as intended. You also need to ensure your specific windows are retuning attributes you can uniquely use. Edge can be a catch22 here. Start this alone to see for yourself.

Comment: I used chatgpt to help me create the script. I did not install any powershell library my work forbid me to do this.

Comment: You using ChatGPT is fine, but that and items like it are not 100% at all. I've been messing with them long before ChatGPT was made public, and on average relative to valid answers, it's around 50%. If you ask it the same question, it will give you a different answer almost every time.  Lastly, as I noted, you have to be able to uniquely know the ID, WindowsHandle, or another unique window attribute to do what you are after, and MSEdge makes this almost impossible. Again, if you just play with starting edge multiple times, and look at the process details, you'll see the reason(s) for failure.

Comment: I have been able to solve the question by using Vscode that simulate the windows key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the question by using Vscode that simulate the windows key.

Here the script I use that will generate an EXE file, this exe file can be trigger with powershell command:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module SendWinKey

    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H0
    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "User32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dwExtraInfo As UInteger)

       Public Sub Main()    
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LWin), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the left Win key down
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.RIGHT), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the right key down
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.RIGHT), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the right key
           keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LWin), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the left Win key
       End Sub
End Module
```